# passing data from UItableviewController to UItableViewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I cannot understand why some values are well passed from the `tableViewController` to my custom `UITableViewCell`, and some others are not.

In my `UItableviewController.cellForRowAtIndexPath` i set up a cell with some values, before returning this cell :

```
cell.label1.text = myCustomObject.id
cell.label2.text = myCustomObject.path
cell.myCustomObjectCellMember = myCustomObject
cell.pathCellMember = myCustomObject.path

return cell
```

On the custom `UITableViewCell` side, in `awakeFromNib` method, the two first cell members are Ok, the two last ones contain `nil`.

The only difference between the two first cell members and the two last ones is that the two first are declared as `IBOutlet` and linked to the storyboard, while the two others are not linked to the UI. But yet, it should be OK to write in these vars from the `tableViewController`, right ?

Here are the declarations of these variables in the custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!    
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!    
var pathCellMember : String!
var myCustomObjectCellMember: MyCustomObjectCellMember!
```

When logged (inside `UITableViewCell.awakeFromNib`), `label1.text` and `label2.text` show the correct value,
but `pathCellMember` and `myCustomObjectCellMember` display `nil` instead of the value assigned in `UItableviewController.cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

As requested, a more explicit code :

```
  class CustomCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {       

       @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!    
       @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!    
       var pathCellMember : String!
       var myCustomObjectCellMember: MyCustomObjectCellMember!

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()

            println("label1 : \(self.label1.text!)") //displays the value assigned
            println("label2 : \(self.label2.text!)") //displays the value assigned
            println("pathCellMember: \(self.pathCellMember!)") //displays nil
            println("myCustomObjectCellMember.path : \(self.myCustomObjectCellMember.path)") //displays `nil`
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your `awakeFromNib` code and specify where exactly it is being called?

Comment: Posted. And thanks for the edit suggestion

Comment: I don't see how it's possible that you see the assigned values in awakeFromNib. When I put a log in cellForRowAtIndexPath right after the line where the cell is created, that log prints out *after* the logs in the cell. awakeFromNib is just too early to check these values. My logs in the cell show the values that were set in IB, not the ones assigned in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @rdelmar has a good point. You should try checking for the `cell` values in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, not inside `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: The point is i need these values in the custom cell class ; now i understand that awakeFromNib is called early, so only the IBOutlet variables are available, which can explain why my non-IBOutlet vars are unavailable at this point - at this time,  but is there any other method i can use to get the values and use them, inside the custom UITableViewCell class ?

Comment: You need to read these values from inside your custom `UITableViewCell`? Why not create and expose a method that could be called from inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then?

Comment: This is what i did at first, but i needed a `MPMoviePlayerController` on each row, with a singleTap listener performed with a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. The behavior was not satisfying : a tap on the first or second row was always detected on the last row. so i decided to move this logic to the cell class, so a specific behavior would be attached to each instantiated cell. But i met this problem with these values i cannot pass ...

Comment: @rdelmar first log i see is the one i have on the first line of `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` ; then i got logs from the custom cell class, in `awakeFromNib` . Note that the logs at the end of `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` come *after* the log of `awakeFromNib`. So we start executing  `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` then `awakeFromNib` and finally `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ends. But this doesnt explain why the IBOutlets vars are well assigned and retrieved on the custom cell class side, and not the others vars

Comment: @TarikZouine: you could either try moving these assignments to `tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)` instead of `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` or going back to using `UITapGestureRecognizer`s and asking another question (that should be easily solvable).

Comment: @AlohaSilver @DCGoD You are both pointing the same direction, i will go back to put my code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, or try with `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath ` and deal with whatever `UITapGestureRecognizers` issue comes up there... Although i still cannot understand why the non IBOutlet class members are lost once i get to the custom UITableView class. Thanks anyway to all of you for your time and wise advice

Answer (score 2):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath is where you will reuse (deque) each cell. This is where you need to assign your vars values to each cell. While awake does set the initial values they will only fire the first time before the cell is reused. Assign everything in cellForRow or willDisplayCell (background colors, etc).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/

*Discussion
For performance reasons, a table view’s data source should generally reuse UITableViewCell objects when it assigns cells to rows in its tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. A table view maintains a queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has marked for reuse. Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a new cell for the table view. This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.
If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method instead.*

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath, i do use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier forIndexPath. And to this cell newly created, i assign some values, inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. But after that, the only vars i can read in awakeFromNib are the IBOutlets ones and not the two other vars

Comment: Wait, why are you using awakeFromNib after that though? Everything needs to be done in cellForRow for any new cells. You can access your other variables from in there when you create a reference to your custom cell class. Post your cellForRowAtIndexPath function. I have a feeling your using UITableViewCell for the class instead of the custom CustomCellTableViewCell class.

Comment: I am facing same problem . and what the solution of this problem .
how can i transfer data from into custom UITableviewCell class ? 
@Mark McCorkle